# how do you search for a particular keyword within a php file?

Tags: linux, ssh, centos

I'm trying to search for a word/phrase within all the php files and all sub-directories where the command is run from. I'm using ssh with root access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
find . -type f -name \*php|xargs grep -i yourword
```

Comment: I just want a list of all the php files that contain the keyword and not the contents inside. Is that possible?

Comment: that's perfect, but how can it now only show the results where the keyword was actually found?

Comment: `-n` option will print the line numbers of where the matches were found.